# Cancel the gesture handler temporary

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I get gesture like this in mainScene

```
// listen for swipes to the left
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeLeft= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

// listen for swipes to the right
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRight= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

and I added newLayer(CCNode) like layer on this mainScene

```
[mainScene addChild:newLayer];
```

When I swipe on newLayer, mainScene gesture handler is called.

I want to off the mainScene's swipe gesture handler during newLayer is added.

How can I make it ?

Comment: Are you saying mainScene has a swipe gesture recognizer for its current main view and you want the layer's recognizer to be handled first?

Comment: Actually, layer doesn't have swipe recoginizer. I don't want to make mainScene's recoginizer react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` or any of the other methods specified by the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol as seen here [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:)

For example you might try...

```
static NSMutableArray *_swipes;
static BOOL _shouldCancel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _swipes = @[].mutableCopy;
    _shouldCancel = YES;
    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [mainScene gestureRecognizers]) {
        if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            gesture.delegate = (id)self;
            [_swipes addObject:gesture];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return ![_swipes containsObject:gestureRecognizer] && _shouldCancel;
}
```

This way you can modify `_shouldCancel` to be `NO` or `YES` depending on when you want the swipe to be disabled.